# Get username in Twig

Tags: theming, hooks

How would I go about making the currently logged in user's username available as a Twig variable in yamlform.html.twig? (From the [YAML Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/yamlform) module.) I know there's something to do with the **themename.theme** PHP file, but I know next to nothing about the Drupal API and all of my copy-pasting hook_preprocess functions has turned up nil.

Answer (score 3):

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess(&$variables, $hook, $info) {
  $variables['current_user_name'] = $variables['user']->getDisplayName();
}
```

in twig template:

```
{{current_user_name}}
```

With this solution current user name available in all twig template.